# Background image hides all GUI design components

Tags: java, image, swing, background

I am working on GUI application where i have used swing components to design GUI. I want to set background image for my form but when i set image it overlaps all components used to design GUI.

First my form without background image is as below shown,

[image]

My code for this is,

### Login.java

```
public class Login extends JFrame{
    public static JFrame myFrame;
    public LoginPanel loginPanel;

    public Login() throws IOException
    {
        initilize();
    }

    public void initilize()throws IOException {

        myFrame = new JFrame("Message"){ 
            private Image backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/Sky.jpg"));
            public void paint( Graphics g ) { 
                super.paint(g);
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        myFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        loginPanel = new LoginPanel();

        //Panel
        Container c = myFrame.getContentPane();

        c.add(loginPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        myFrame.setSize(300, 150);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    } 

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    new Login();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### LoginPanel.java

```
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public JLabel user_no=null;
    public JLabel password=null;
    public JButton btn_login = null;
    public JButton btn_newUser = null;
    public JTextField usernameField=null;
    public JPasswordField passwordField=null;
    public static String userNo;
    public ArrayList msgList = new ArrayList();

    public LoginPanel()
    {
        initilize();
        initConnection();
    }

    private void initilize() {

        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 285;
        size.height = 150;
        setPreferredSize(size);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Login Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP));

        user_no = new JLabel("User No : ");

        password = new JLabel("Password : ");

        usernameField = new JTextField(14);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField(14);

        btn_login = new JButton("Login");

        btn_newUser = new JButton("New User");

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //// First column /////////////////////////

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(user_no, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(password, gc);

        //// Second column
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(usernameField, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(passwordField, gc);

        // Final row
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        add(btn_login, gc);

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        add(btn_newUser, gc);

    }

    private void initConnection() {
        btn_login.addActionListener(this);
        btn_newUser.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource().equals(btn_login))
        {
            userNo = usernameField.getText();
            String userPwd = passwordField.getText();
            System.out.println(userNo+" "+userPwd);
            Connection con = ConnectionImpl.getConnection();

            try
            {
                PreparedStatement pstmt;

                String sql = "SELECT sender_no,pwd FROM tb_login where sender_no ='"+userNo+"'"; 

                pstmt= con.prepareStatement(sql);

                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                if(rs.next())
                {
                    if(userNo.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(1))&&userPwd.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(2)))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Successfull login");

                        String sql2 = "Select msg from tb_msg where sender_no='"+userNo+"'";

                        pstmt= con.prepareStatement(sql2);

                        ResultSet rs2 = pstmt.executeQuery();

                        while(rs2.next())
                        {
                            msgList.add(rs2.getString(1));
                        }
                        System.out.println("msgList = "+msgList.size());

                        Login.myFrame.dispose();
                        new AddMessage(userNo,msgList);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(e.getSource().equals(btn_newUser))
        {
            Login.myFrame.dispose();
            new NewUser();
        }
    }

}
```

After setting background image it look like this,

[image]

It hides component for `JButton`, `JLabel`.

Comment: you need to draw the image and then run the drawing for all subcomponents manually instead of calling super.paint(g);

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  E.G. This has nothing to do with `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. paint `Image` to the `LoginPanel (JPanel)` instead of `ContentPane` (not good idead to paint directly to the `JFrame`)
2. for `JPanel` to use `paintComponent(`) instead of `paint(for JFrame`)

Answer (score 4):

The code needs to be something closer to this:

[image: Login panel]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Login extends JFrame{
    public static JFrame myFrame;
    public LoginPanel loginPanel;

    public Login() throws IOException
    {
        initilize();
    }

    public void initilize()throws IOException {
        BufferedImage backgroundImage = new BufferedImage(400,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        myFrame = new JFrame("Message");
        myFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        loginPanel = new LoginPanel(backgroundImage);

        //Panel
        Container c = myFrame.getContentPane();

        c.add(loginPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        //myFrame.setSize(300, 150);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    } 

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    new Login();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class LoginPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public JLabel user_no=null;
    public JLabel password=null;
    public JButton btn_login = null;
    public JButton btn_newUser = null;
    public JTextField usernameField=null;
    public JPasswordField passwordField=null;
    public static String userNo;
    public ArrayList msgList = new ArrayList();

    private BufferedImage backgroundImage;

    public LoginPanel(BufferedImage backgroundImage)
    {
        this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
        initilize();
        initConnection();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }

    private void initilize() {

        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 285;
        size.height = 150;
        setPreferredSize(size);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Login Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP));

        user_no = new JLabel("User No : ");
        password = new JLabel("Password : ");
        usernameField = new JTextField(14);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(14);
        btn_login = new JButton("Login");
        btn_newUser = new JButton("New User");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //// First column /////////////////////////

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(user_no, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(password, gc);

        //// Second column
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(usernameField, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(passwordField, gc);

        // Final row
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        add(btn_login, gc);

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        add(btn_newUser, gc);

    }

    private void initConnection() {
        btn_login.addActionListener(this);
        btn_newUser.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource().equals(btn_login))
        {
            userNo = usernameField.getText();
            String userPwd = passwordField.getText();
            System.out.println(userNo+" "+userPwd);
            Connection con = null;

            try
            {
                PreparedStatement pstmt;
                String sql = "SELECT sender_no,pwd FROM tb_login where sender_no ='"+userNo+"'"; 
                pstmt= con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next())
                {
                    if(userNo.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(1))&&userPwd.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(2)))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Successfull login");
                        String sql2 = "Select msg from tb_msg where sender_no='"+userNo+"'";
                        pstmt= con.prepareStatement(sql2);
                        ResultSet rs2 = pstmt.executeQuery();

                        while(rs2.next())
                        {
                            msgList.add(rs2.getString(1));
                        }
                        System.out.println("msgList = "+msgList.size());

                        Login.myFrame.dispose();
                        //new AddMessage(userNo,msgList);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(e.getSource().equals(btn_newUser))
        {
            Login.myFrame.dispose();
            //new NewUser();
        }
    }
}
```

### Further tips

1. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
2. Don't extend frame, just use an instance, but..
3. In this case don't use a frame at all, but instead show the log-in in a `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`.